# Are temperature increases discrete?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, discrete

Are [temperature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temperature) increases ever discrete in nature, or is it a continuous variable?

If a discrete case exists, is there any material that exhibits particularly strange behavior?

Answer (score 1):

If you stick with the Statistical Mechanics formalism, then temperature is discrete.

Entropy S is  $ S = k_B\ln(\Gamma) $, where $\Gamma$ is the number of available quantum states,

and temperature is

$T =  \frac{dE}{dS} $ , where E is the total kinetic energy of the system.

Since every quantity there is discrete, so is temperature.

Comment: Temperature is only defined for infinite temperature baths, so what you are "measuring" there is not temperature.